# How to copy files from Windows to Linux HDFS directly

Tags: linux, windows, scp, hadoop, dfs

I am trying to copy a large amount files to Hadoop HIVE. Right now I am doing this via a two-step scripts.

- Step 1: Powershell scripts copying files from Windows to Linux using
  Putty scp tool.
- Step 2: Bash scripts copying files from Linux to HDFS using Hadoop
  put command.

Is there a way to do this via just one step?

Comment: I tried out HortonWorks' Sandbox. Via Ambari I can upload files (one file a time) directly into HDFS. I wonder whether HortonWorks provide any tool to automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one solution. I mounted the windows share to the Linux box so I could treat the window share as a local Linux path, then I copied files directly from that path to a HDFS location.